# css resize 2 images horizontal

Tags: css, image, html

I'm stuck on a piece of code pretty basic and I think I must not know the correct syntax.

I want to display 2 images side by side (horizontally so X | X) and that it is automatically resizes depending on the width of the screen ...

My problem is that the second image when the screen is reduced in width falls below the first. I tried to fix the height of my DIV Contener but the second image comes out of it  ... would you know how to fix that please? Enclosed my current piece of code.

```
<div style="width:100%;max-height:150px;border:1px solid black;" >
<img src="http://chezsilvia.c.h.pic.centerblog.net/o/3963dc3b.jpg" style="max-width:100%;"/>
<img src="http://chezsilvia.c.h.pic.centerblog.net/o/3963dc3b.jpg" style="max-width:100%;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: relative;` on your wrapper and `width: 50%; float: left;` on your images

```
<div style="position: relative; float: left; width: 100%; border: solid 1px #000">
    <img src="yourPath.jpg" style="float: left; width:50%;">
    <img src="yourPath.jpg" style="float: left; width:50%;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Needs `width: 50%;` and `float:left;` for the left image

Heres a jsFiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/vwMWn/18/

Your Code:

```
<div style="width:100%;max-height:150px;border:1px solid black;" >
     <img src="http://chezsilvia.c.h.pic.centerblog.net/o/3963dc3b.jpg" style="max-width:50%; float:left"/>
     <img src="http://chezsilvia.c.h.pic.centerblog.net/o/3963dc3b.jpg" style="max-width:50%;"/>
</div>
```